# Error 0x80200013 when downloading apps from Windows Store

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store

I'm using windows 8, a lot of times when I try to download an app from the store I get error 0x80200013. I tried searching the web but only found articles about this error related to Windows Update, not Windows Store.

Comment: The problem is either with [BITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) (same source for WU errors as well) or your network hardware.

Comment: Windows store is related to Windows Update I think. Run the official Apps troubleshooter first http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/apps.diagcab

Comment: I'm getting the same thing - wondering if it has to do with me switching from a local to a domain user?  Anyway, tried the troubleshooter which, on the surface, claimed to change some things, but by looking at the details, it didn't manage to accomplish anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out that disabling the use of a web proxy seemed to fix it for me.
My IE proxy settings were auto-configured on my home domain (in order to use Privoxy for browsing).  When I turned off auto-configuration, all apps and updates in my Store queue installed as they should.

Now I just need to figure out how to keep using Privoxy while ensuring that BITS/Store can keep working.

Comment: 0x80200013 means BG_E_INSUFFICIENT_RANGE_SUPPORT

If you are in corporation network, check proxy servers to ensure that they are configured correctly to support range requests. Nice work Robert!